# How to fade in and fade out text in loop

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I want the text to fade in and fade out in the loop never stop it. like, come fade in then out again and again with HTML CSS. I'm going to share with you my code which just does fade in not do fade out and loop also not so anybody sees my code and told me how I can do that with HTML OR CSS because I want to use this animated type text on WordPress website with one build on the Elementor page builder. so please help. Thank You

```css
.fade-in {
  animation: fadeIn ease 10s;
  -webkit-animation: fadeIn ease 10s;
  -moz-animation: fadeIn ease 10s;
  -o-animation: fadeIn ease 10s;
  -ms-animation: fadeIn ease 10s;
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@-o-keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@-ms-keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
```

```html
<h1 class="fade-in">Its just fade in not out i want fade in and out in loop never stop it.</h1>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `animation-direction` and `animation-iteration` properties.

Combined into a shorthand, you get a property like : `animation: fadeIn infinite alternate ease 2s`

Change duration as necessary

```css
.fade-in {
  animation: fadeIn infinite alternate ease 2s;  
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<h1 class="fade-in">Its just fade in not out i want fade in and out in loop never stop it.</h1>
```

Comment: it's working fine for me we make it more smoothly?

Comment: @Aziz You can try different `ease` types and durations https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-timing-function

Comment: It's Fine I check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-timing-function site I use few codes but It seems like the letters are just blinking, I need them to come in one a time in sequential order (fading in).

Comment: You should ask a new question for that, its not clear in your current question